# How can I format a json, with dynamic keys?

Tags: javascript, json

```
  var data= [{_id: "5a93cbd49ae761a4015f6346", nombre: "Chicago - Missouri", longitud: "-94.6807924", latitud: "38.287606"},
{ _id: "5a93ca539ae761a4015f6344", nombre: "Boston - Central Falss", longitud: "-71.4111895", latitud: "41.8902971"},
{ _id: "5a93ccbf9ae761a4015f6349", nombre: "Houston - Dallas", longitud: "-97.0117365", latitud: "32.8209296"}]

var d=[];
for(var i in data){
    d.push({ data[i].nombre:data[i]["_id"] })
}
```

I would like to have a json with structure

```
{ "nombre":"_id" }
```

for example:

```
 { "Chicago - Missouri":"5a93cbd49ae761a4015f6346"}
 { "Boston - Central Falss- Missouri": "5a93ca539ae761a4015f6344" }4
```

what is my mistake?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an object first, add the data and push it into `d`

```js
var data= [{
  _id: "5a93cbd49ae761a4015f6346",
  nombre: "Chicago - Missouri", 
  longitud: "-94.6807924", 
  latitud: "38.287606"
},{ 
  _id: "5a93ca539ae761a4015f6344", 
  nombre: "Boston - Central Falss", 
  longitud: "-71.4111895", 
  latitud: "41.8902971"
},{ 
  _id: "5a93ccbf9ae761a4015f6349", 
  nombre: "Houston - Dallas", 
  longitud: "-97.0117365", 
  latitud: "32.8209296"
}]

var d=[];
for(var i in data){
    var temp = {};
    temp[ data[i].nombre ] = data[i]["_id"];
    d.push(temp)
}

console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try This -

```js
var data= [{_id: "5a93cbd49ae761a4015f6346", nombre: "Chicago - Missouri", longitud: "-94.6807924", latitud: "38.287606"},
{ _id: "5a93ca539ae761a4015f6344", nombre: "Boston - Central Falss", longitud: "-71.4111895", latitud: "41.8902971"},
{ _id: "5a93ccbf9ae761a4015f6349", nombre: "Houston - Dallas", longitud: "-97.0117365", latitud: "32.8209296"}]

var d =[];
for(var i in data){
 var pushObj = {};
    pushObj[data[i].nombre] = data[i]["_id"];
    d.push(pushObj)
}
console.log(d);
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.map()` is much faster. It runs about four times faster than pushing onto a new array one element at a time. And in my eyes it's simpler, but that's a matter of opinion.

`var newData = data.map(
      function(train){ 
        let obj = {};
        obj[train["_id"]] = train["nombre"];
        return obj;
      }
    );

console.log(newData);`